# saving email address Facebook + Parse (Swift)

Tags: facebook, swift, authentication, parse-platform

So I'm trying to use Parse + Facebook to login people in to my app, but am experiencing difficulty saving the actual name/email address of the user. I'm only using Facebook authentication for now, and my right now a user is able to login/reigster but it stores the username as an encoded string (ie 6zAhVeAklzyKnA5weq29) instead of an actual name. Furthermore, no email address is store (I am using Parse default "user" table).

Here is my code

main view  controller:

```
class homeViewController: UIViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

var noteObjects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
let permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    Utils.logInWithFacebook()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {

       // Utils.logInWithFacebook()
        let logInViewController = MyLogInViewController()
        logInViewController.signUpController = PFSignUpViewController()
        //self.presentViewController(logInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        logInViewController.fields = PFLogInFields.Facebook

        logInViewController.delegate = self

        var signUpViewController = PFSignUpViewController()

        signUpViewController.delegate = self

        logInViewController.signUpController = signUpViewController

        self.presentViewController(logInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }else {
       //  Utils.logInWithFacebook()
        var username = PFUser.currentUser().username
        nameLabel.text = username
        self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore()
        self.fetchAllObjects()
    }
}


func fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore() {

    var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Note")

    query.fromLocalDatastore()
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {
            var temp: NSArray = objects as NSArray
            self.noteObjects = temp.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
            //                self.tableView.reloadData()
        }else {
            println(error.userInfo)
        }
    }
}

func fetchAllObjects() {

    PFObject.unpinAllObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)

    var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Note")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects, block: nil)
            self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore()
        }else {
            println(error.userInfo)
        }
    }
}
func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, shouldBeginLogInWithUsername username: String!, password: String!) -> Bool {

    if (!username.isEmpty || !password.isEmpty) {
        return true
    }else {
        return false
    }
}

func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, didLogInUser user: PFUser!) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, didFailToLogInWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("Failed to log in...")
}

func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController!, shouldBeginSignUp info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Bool {
    if let password = info?["password"] as? String {
        // return password.utf16Count >= 8
        return count(password.utf16) >= 8
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController!, didSignUpUser user: PFUser!) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController!, didFailToSignUpWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("Failed to sign up...")
}

func signUpViewControllerDidCancelSignUp(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController!) {
    println("User dismissed sign up.")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    //var upcoming: AddNoteTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddNoteTableViewController
    if (segue.identifier == "editNote") {

    }
 }
}
```

Utils class where I have my Facebook login code

```
import Foundation

class Utils {

 class func notLoggedIn() -> Bool {
    let user = PFUser.currentUser()
    // here I assume that a user must be linked to Facebook
    return user == nil || !PFFacebookUtils.isLinkedWithUser(user)
}
class func loggedIn() -> Bool {
    return !notLoggedIn()
}


class func logInWithFacebook() {
    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(["public_profile", "user_friends", "email"]) {
        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if user == nil {
            NSLog("The user cancelled the Facebook login (user is nil)")
        } else {
            NSLog("The user successfully logged in with Facebook (user is NOT nil)")
            // HERE I SET AN ACL TO THE INSTALLATION
            if let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation() {
                let acl = PFACL(user: PFUser.currentUser()) // Only user can write
                acl.setPublicReadAccess(true) // Everybody can read
                acl.setWriteAccess(true, forRoleWithName: "Admin") // Also Admins can write
                installation.ACL = acl
                //installation.saveEventually()
            }
            // THEN I GET THE USERNAME AND fbId
            Utils.obtainUserNameAndFbId()
        }
    }
}


class func obtainUserNameAndFbId() {
    if notLoggedIn() {
        return
    }
    let user = PFUser.currentUser() // Won't be nil because is logged in
    // RETURN IF WE ALREADY HAVE A USERNAME AND FBID (note that we check the fbId because Parse automatically fills in the username with random numbers)
    if let fbId = user["fbId"] as? String {
        if !fbId.isEmpty {
            println("we already have a username and fbId -> return")
            return
        }
    }
    // REQUEST TO FACEBOOK
    println("performing request to FB for username and IDF...")
    if let session = PFFacebookUtils.session() {
        if session.isOpen {
            println("session is open")
            FBRequestConnection.startForMeWithCompletionHandler({ (connection: FBRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                println("done me request")
                if error != nil {
                    println("facebook me request - error is not nil :(")
                } else {
                    println("facebook me request - error is nil :)")
                    println(result)
                    // You have 2 ways to access the result:
                    // 1)
                    println(result["name"])
                    println(result["id"])
                    println(result["email"])
                    // 2)
                    println(result.name)
                    println(result.objectID)
                    println(result.email)
                    // Save to Parse:
                    PFUser.currentUser().username = result.email
                    PFUser.currentUser().email = result.email
                    PFUser.currentUser().setValue(result.objectID, forKey: "fbId")
                    PFUser.currentUser().setValue(result.email, forKey: "email")

                    //PFUser.currentUser().saveEventually()
                    // Always use saveEventually if you want to be sure that the save will succeed
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The login screen the user logs into for you to utilise Facebook API won't give you the user's email. It will instead give you an Access Token which is the `6zAhVeAklzyKnA5weq29` you are seeing. Unless you create a custom Web View then you will not be able to store the user's email. You can however store the access token in the NSUserDefaults or in your case Parse (i recommend just using NSUserDefaults as it's easier) and use that to make calls from the Facebook API.